# SQL Connection with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
TextBox1=Server Name

TextBox2=Db  Name

TextBox3=User Name

TextBox4=Password
```

I declared as a variable  "Server Name,dbname,user name,password".My question is; I want to test my sql connection on another machine by them using.
   How can I do that with c#?

```
 //// SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection

 ////("Data Source="+  server   +";Initial Catalog=DATA;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` for this scenario:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

builder.DataSource = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
builder.InitialCatalog = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
builder.UserID = TextBox3.Text.Trim();
builder.Password = TextBox4.Text.Trim();

string result = builder.ConnectionString;
```

This builds up the connection string and returns it as a result in the end.

Also: you might want to use more descriptive names for your textboxes! `tbxDataSource, tbxInitialCatalog` etc. would be **much** better than `TextBox1, TextBox2` etc.

Comment: Thats why I love Stack overflow :) ... thanx Marc new thing....One Upvote from me..

Answer (score 1):

little modified pranay's answer

```
   bool TestConnection()
   {
       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string.Format(@"user id={0}; password={1};Data Source={2}; 
                                   Trusted_Connection=yes;
                                   Initial Catalog={3}; 
                                   connection timeout=30", userName,password,serverName,database));
       try
       {
           conn.Open();
           return true;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
```